# Cannot run Mocha tests with phantomjs-node

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to use [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) with mocha to run some tests

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.open('http://localhost:8900').then(function(status) {
            console.log(status);
                 if ( status === "success" ) {
              page.injectJs("../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js");
              page.injectJs("../node_modules/chai/chai.js");

              //inject your test reporter
              page.injectJs("testMocha/reporter.js");

              //inject your tests
              tests.forEach(function(test) {
                 page.injectJs(test);
              })

               page.property('evaluate').then(function() {
                  window.mocha.run();
                });
            }else{
              ph.exit();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I run the file with

```
node myFile.js
```

But when I run the file nothing shows up in the console, none of my tests are run, and the script hangs.

If I do it without phantomjs-node I'm able to run and display my tests, launching the file with

```
phantomjs myFile.js
```

but I need phantomjs-node to do other things needed for my tests. How can I mocha with phantomjs-node?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that first i needed to start the evaluate this way :

```
page.evaluate(function() {
```

I thought i had to do `page.property('evaluate').then(function() {` cause i was using phantomjs-node but that's not the case

And second the reason i couldn't see my tests results from mocha is because in my reporter file i was displaying the result with callPhantom :

```
window.callPhantom({ message: args.join(" ") });
```

But with phantomjs-node this doesn't seem to work so instead just do a simple console.log

```
console.log( args.join(" ") );
```

An exemple of the reporter i use and a great tutorial on how to use phantomJS and mocha together can be found there :

http://doublenegative.com/phantomjs-mocha-and-chai-for-functional-testing/